# how to get the value from table data(td) by clicking on that and pass it 4 input field as a number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having  the otp form which needs to pass the value from table td values to four different input field. I want the solution for this ?I have already done passing that but the value is passing even though the input is null it seems when i submits.number  should not be visible when press the td.but in place star should be visible after entering the number.

```js
$("#tblMain  tbody td").on('click', function() {
    if($("#empname").val()==="") {
      $("#empname").val($(this).text());
    } else {
    if($("#empname2").val()==="") {  
      $("#empname2").val($(this).text());
    } else {
    if($("#empname3").val()==="") {  
      $("#empname3").val($(this).text());
    } else {
    if($("#empname4").val()==="") {  
      $("#empname4").val($(this).text());
    } } } }
});
$("#backspace").on('click', function() {

   document.getElementById("empname").value="";
   document.getElementById("empname2").value="";
  document.getElementById("empname3").value="";
  document.getElementById("empname4").value="";
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<table align="center" id="tblMain" border="1" style="cursor: pointer;">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>*</td>
    <td id="backspace">back</td>
  </tr>
 
 </table>
 
<input type="text" id="empname" value=""/>
<input type="text" id="empname2" value=""/>
<input type="text" id="empname3" value=""/>
<input type="text" id="empname4" value=""/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-xl-8" id="otp_submit" >Submit OTP</button>
</form>
```

Could you please anyone help on this?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Maybe you should be using hidden inputs?

Comment: i want the form input field where we enter  otp?

Comment: it is otp verification form

Comment: Store the numbers in hidden inputs, and display `*` in the visible input fields.

Comment: how to get the table td value and pass it to four  input ?

Comment: can you give me the code for that if possible?

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't that what your code does?

Comment: no.it is just passing the value to input filed nothing else is doing.but for me 1.the value should pass to input field from td table. 2.the value sholud not be visible rather should be *.3.back button can delete that entered otp as well.

Comment: First click goes to the first input, second click goes to the second input, third click goes to third input, fourth click goes to fourth input. What else do you need to do to pass the td values to four inputs?

Comment: but the value is passing but the input filed is null if i check it in console

Comment: You can't see input values in the console.

Comment: empname
:
""
empname2
:
""
empname3
:
""
empname4
:
""

Comment: by using angular we can

Comment: if i type the value i can see that input has some value

Comment: Just use array of four element and pivot position variable. if you need to go back  just decrease it and delete value of element in array.

Comment: can you write the code for that?

Comment: can you please help on this?

Comment: Maybe I still misunderstand. What are you checking in the console? I thought you meant you're looking in the Elements tab. You won't see the value that's typed into a field in the `<input>` element there.

Comment: Yes I m not able to see values in input field.if I type something it is actually getting the value but after submitting the input field still null I can see null in the console

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure but you can use data attribute to store values

```
$("#tblMain  tbody td").on('click', function() {
    if($("#empname").val()==="") {
      $('#empname').data('option',$(this).text()); //setter  
      $("#empname").val("*");
    } else {
    if($("#empname2").val()==="") {  
      $('#empname2').data('option',$(this).text()); //setter  
      $("#empname2").val("*");
    } else {
    if($("#empname3").val()==="") {
      $('#empname3').data('option',$(this).text()); //setter  
      $("#empname3").val("*");
    } else {
    if($("#empname4").val()==="") {  
      $('#empname4').data('option',$(this).text()); //setter  
      $("#empname4").val("*");
    } } } }
});
$("#backspace").on('click', function() {

   document.getElementById("empname").value="";
   $('#empname').data('option',""); //setter 
   document.getElementById("empname2").value="";
   $('#empname2').data('option',""); //setter                                    
   document.getElementById("empname3").value="";
   $('#empname3').data('option',""); //setter 
   document.getElementById("empname4").value="";
   $('#empname4').data('option',""); //setter 
  });
```

You could use queue instead of that many if statements.

---

edit

not queue but just array

```
<input type="text" class="classIsBetter" id="empname" value=""/>
<input type="text" class="classIsBetter" id="empname2" value=""/>
<input type="text" class="classIsBetter" id="empname3" value=""/>
<input type="text" class="classIsBetter" id="empname4" value=""/>

elements = document.querySelectorAll(".classIsBetter");
currentPosition = 0;
$("td").click(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('id') == "backspace") {
    currentPosition -= 1;
    elements[currentPosition].dataset.option = "";
    elements[currentPosition].value = "";
    return;
  } else {
    elements[currentPosition].dataset.option = $(this).text(); //setter
    elements[currentPosition].value = $(this).text();
    currentPosition++;
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/66ecj8f5/2/

Comment: thankyou but it  is passing the star not the value i can see it in the empname=" " it is null still.can you please  use queue instead of that many if statements.can you give me the code

Comment: #nave Please use punctuation. It is little hard to locate flow of your program with this description.

Comment: ya Ok Kairat Thanks

Comment: zone.js:195 Uncaught TypeError: elements[currentPosition].data is not a function
    at HTMLTableCellElement.eval (eval at webpackJsonp../node_modules/script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:6:31)

Comment: can you please your array code in js fiddel sapart?so it will be more understandable for me?

Comment: #nave use link that i put

Comment: still value is not getting stroed

Comment: #nave Where do you wan't to store it
i did without submitting form . it was just table with data

Comment: if i am enter the value in the input field it gives the value but if i click the tr values in the input field  idont see any value in the console.and

Comment: i dont want to store anyware let the entered details to be store in the input field to compare with database otp?

Comment: Your question was how to delete one element from list when pressed the button... Now you need to solve it separately

Comment: i am using angular

Comment: i am sorry i dont see any link from you?

Comment: You need to do it differently using angular.... Can't help now . it is different direction

Comment: could you please store it someware after submitting beacause thats is only my biggest issue?

Comment: i want to know where it is stirng the value after submitting

Comment: i want you to do after submitting also?can you please do that if possible?

Comment: Hi are you there?

Comment: i will take care of angular part.

Comment: i want only when i am passing the date the form needs to be get the value and when i submit i need to get the value and compare thats it?comapration and i will take care

Comment: everything in javascript itself.can you do that in normal html and javascript only?

Comment: #nave You get answer on what you ask. It is not freelance exchange portal where somebody makes for you. you didn't even chose best answer...

Comment: No in my question I was told u value is passing able to see the numbers.but after submitting I don't see the value......and thanks for back button functionality

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question, the simplest way of achieving that would be adding **`required`** attribute to each input field. That way the Browser would check if any of the required input field is empty (before submitting).

Also, use input type as password to hide it, and display the value as asterisks (star).

```html
<form>
<table align="center" id="tblMain" border="1" style="cursor: pointer;">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>*</td>
    <td id="backspace">back</td>
  </tr>
 
 </table>
 
<input type="password" id="empname" value="" required/>
<input type="password" id="empname2" value="" required/>
<input type="password" id="empname3" value="" required/>
<input type="password" id="empname4" value="" required/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-xl-8" id="otp_submit" >Submit OTP</button>
</form>
```

Comment: this is not my ques.

Comment: thanks but i need to pass the value from tABLE  date in to for4  input field the value should not be visible but i want star should be visible while the user type?

Comment: I've updated the answer. .check if that's what you want.

Comment: I've changed the input type from text to password.

Comment: 1.the value should pass to input field from td table. 2.the value sholud not be visible rather should be *.3.back button can delete that entered otp as well.

Comment: Updated! <td>back</td> was missing backspace as an id in it ---- <td id="backspace">back</td>

Comment: hi thanks i dont want front end i have everything i need javascript functionality how to pass the value from input to td and how to pass the td value to 4 input if u know answser this?

Comment: see my javascript is working but it passing the value if i submit it is showing the requred message to enter eventhough if we have value in input field

Comment: I am sorry, i don't get you.  Please try to elaborate, may be I can help.

Comment: 1.i can enter values by clicking the  table td in four input field, 2.after entering the button should be enable but it is not happening if the input has the value by seeing but it is not having the value if i console that.3.still asking me to enter the details got it

Comment: [screenshot here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bwq2yLDOPM7YZnBod2NzM25fZ2s)  As you said, the values are displayed as asterisks. The back button is working fine.  The correct way to console from input value is    :  console.log(document.getElementById('empname').getAttribute('value'));

Comment: i dont want to do console to output my data some here i want my data should be in the input field?

Comment: thank you @Mithu Mondal .done completed one june17  itself .

Comment: Glad I could help. :)